# elastic search limit results for types

Tags: elasticsearch

i have the following query

```
$queryDefinition = [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [
                        'query_string' => [
                            'default_field' => '_all',
                            'query' => $term
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'must_not' => [],
                'should' => []
            ],
        ],
        //'filter' => [
        //    'limit' => ['value' => 3],
        //],
        'from' => 0,
        'size' => 50,
        'sort' => [],
        'facets' => [
            'types' => [
                    'terms' => ['field' => '_type']
                ]
            ]
    ];
```

in the index we have 5 types, and i would like to show only 3 results from each type, for autocomplete. when i set the filter limit only the results from the first type are filtered, for other types i get all the results.

how can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```json
{
  "aggregations": {
    "types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
      },
      "hits": {
        "top_hits": {
          "size": 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using ElasticSearch 1.4.0, you can use [terms aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on "_type" field and use [top hits aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) as sub aggregation and set its size to 3 (in your case).

Hope that helps.